# Unable to remove or change files after setfacl rwx-command

Tags: permissions, users, setfacl

With root-user, I've executed this command:

```
setfacl -R -d -m u:MYUSER:rwx /myfolder
```

When I then change to that user ( `su MYUSER` ) and try to remove a file ( `rm /myfolder/somefile.sql` then I get the this error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'somefile.sql': Permission denied
```

I can't `mv` it either; then I get this error:

```
mv: cannot move 'somefile.sql' to 'someotherfile.sql': Permission denied
```

I've added `MYUSER` to `/etc/sudoers`, - so when I run: `sudo rm /myfolder/somefile.sql`, then I'm prompted for `MYUSER`s password; and then it works. But I need it to work without `sudo`, so I can run it as a crontab-job.

If I write `getfacl /myfolder`, then I get this output:

```
# file: /myfolder/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:MYUSER:rwx       <-- That looks right, doesn't it?
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

... Why in the name of Zeus can't I remove files in this directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MYUSER` is a default owner, but not an effective owner.

You need to run both

```
setfacl -R -d -m u:MYUSER:rwx /myfolder
setfacl -R    -m u:MYUSER:rwx /myfolder
```

note second command do not have a default (`-d`/`--default`) flag.

this sould result in `getfacl` giving

```
# file: /myfolder/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:MYUSER:rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:MYUSER:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Answer (score 1):

`setfacl` (it's about the same for `firewalld`) should always be run twice. Once with `-d` to set the default permissions that will affect newly created files and without it for the actual files.